# Why does this MOSFET heat up?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, led-driver

Does anyone have an idea why this MOSFET warms up in this circuit? In simulation everything looks good, but the real MOSFET heats up to around 60°C.

I am designing this circuit for 1.2A. Measured voltage by scope V<sub>gs</sub> is 10.6V, V<sub>ds</sub> is 60mV; the measurement was done with a DC voltage of 3.3V on the input of the optocoupler without any PWM.

I can´t find any mistake in this circuit.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to the datasheet of the exact mosfet you are using? A VDS of 60mv at a current of 1.2A should only produce 0.07W of heating, which is barely significant

Comment: Exactly! I am using [IRFZ24N] (https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFZ24N-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563af6ce21f7)

Comment: Seems this is a DC circuit (not PWM). Can you measure Vds?

Comment: I am using for driving of circuit PCA9685, for test purpose i set output of PCA to 100% ON. Measured Vds is around 60-90mV.

Comment: 90mVx1.2A=108mW. 60°C pretty normal temperature.

Comment: Based on datasheet parameter of thermal resistanc junction to ambient 62°C/W i think the change of the temperature should be only aprox. 6°C, based on your calculation of power dissipation. Temperature of ambient is around 20°C.

Comment: Something is wrong. With these resistors around the optocoupler I would expect much lower vgs.

Comment: Okay, break it down. You've measured Vgs and Vds. Double check them. Then break the connection to the drain and measure the current into the transistor drain. Maybe the current is higher than expected. I don't think it is, but if you don't have an oscilloscope, put a large capacitor (like 100uF) from gate to source just in case it could somehow be oscillating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *the real MOSFET heats up to around 60°C*

Firstly, let me say that you don't necessarily need a pile of power to warm something up by what may seem to be large amounts. If there isn't much airflow around the MOSFET then a few hundred milliwatts can easily warm it by several tens of °C and probably within a few dozen seconds. The next thing to say is that 60°C isn't a particularly troublesome temperature for most MOSFETs.

Back to the question....

The [PC817D](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/download_datasheet.php?id=746895&part-number=PC817D) isn't capable of driving the MOSFET's gate sufficiently in these circumstances. If you read the PC817D data sheet, you'll be lucky to get 20 mA through it at a saturation voltage of about 5 volts. With 20 mA into R3, the voltage developed across gate and source will be about 5 volts.

You report that the voltage measured between gate and source is 10.6 volts and, that can only occur if the PC817D output was a short-circuit. Do the math; if the collector and emitter are shorted then the voltage across R3 is this: -

$$24\text{ volts}\cdot \dfrac{270}{270+270+68} = 10.66\text{ volts}$$

But, of course you won't get the PC817D output behaving like a pure short-circuit. So basically, I'm disputing your measurements. With my estimation of 5 volts between the MOSFET's gate and source, you might get anything between 100 mV and 200 mV dropped across the partially-conducting MOSFET channel and, that could easily warm the device up a few tens of degrees.

More about the PC817D...

Given that you are driving the PC817D with only about 17 mA, I estimate the PC817D transistor is going to conduct somewhere around 20 mA and be dropping about 5 volts between C and E.

[image]

The above graph is from the PC817D data sheet and red-lined by me. The numbers are typical - extreme limit values could easily mean that the MOSFET is really poorly driven.

I say 17 mA because if you take the 3.3 volts drive voltage to the PC817D's diode and remove the forward volt drop of the diode (about 1.2 volts), this leaves 2.1 volts across the 120 Ω resistor, R5. Simple ohm's law predicts about 17 mA flowing into the photodiode.

And here's the likely volt drop spread across the MOSFET channel (red oval shape): -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your gate drive .Your opto will struggle into the 270 ohm load .If you dont have enough gate source drive the mosfet will not have its specified on resistance and will waste more voltage making more heat .Get things right at 100% duty  cycle  before sorting the pwm.

Answer (score -1):

That circuit is the typical DIY DC/DC converter.

---

It heats up because the on-to-off time, of your M1, is too long.

Your PC817D opto is fast to turn your M1 on, but it's very slow to turn your M1 off.

You should use another PC817D opto that sinks currents from the gate of M1.

---

It heats up because you are requiring from M1 to sink 1.2 A with an initial Rdson of 100 mOhm at room temperature that becomes bigger as M1 temperature goes up.

Comment: Yes, i understand this issue, but i have also problem with heats up if i turn on output for 100% without PWM.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: The OP is using an IRF**Z**24, not an IRF**2**24. Rds-on is only 0.07ohms

Comment: @brhans maybe the OP has IRF224